# How can we add column names in spark as attributes of a pyspark dataframe

Tags: sql, dataframe, pyspark, attributes

I'm looking for a "simple way" to add my table's column names (either by using .schema or .columns or any other way?) to my pyspark dataframe so that when I type "df." my IDE shows me column names as the class attributes, or for example typing "df.columns." does the same procedure I just described. In case you are wondering about the IDE it can be Spyder, VSCode or PyCharm.

Comment: so, you want a dataframe's "column names" as dataframe methods? that's very far fetched because different dataframes will have different column names

Comment: @samkart I don't see why it is farfetched? When you create a session and when build the dataframe from DB table, it can be easily populated.
In fact, in the documentation if a dataframe is created manually, its columns are visible as attributes. I just don't know how to make the table schema be populated when reading from DB (in PySpark examples the schema is manually defined).